# Error: Invariant Violation: Store.__emitChange(): Must be invoked while dispatching

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, reactjs-flux, jestjs, immutable.js

I'm trying to test flux stores. I use `ReduceStore` from `flux/utils`, `jest` v0.7.0. When I dispatch an action with the mocked dispatcher I get an error:

`Error: Invariant Violation: Store.__emitChange(): Must be invoked while dispatching.`

If I use this store in a real browser, it works as expected.

Here is my store:

```
import {ReduceStore} from 'flux/utils';
import Immutable from 'immutable';
import Dispatcher from '../dispatcher';
import actionConstants from '../action-constants';

class EntryStore extends ReduceStore {

  getInitialState() {
    return Immutable.List();
  }

  reduce(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case actionConstants.ENTRIES_REQUEST_SUCCESS:
        return state.merge(action.payload.entries);

      default:
        return state;
    }
  }

}

const instance = new EntryStore(Dispatcher);
export default instance;
```

And, here is a test file:

```
jest.autoMockOff();
jest.mock('../../dispatcher');
const actionConstants = require('../../action-constants');    

describe('EntryStore', function() {

  let Dispatcher, EntryStore, callback;

  // mock entries
  entries = [1, 2, 3];
  // mock actions
  const Immutable = require('immutable');
  const entriesRequestSuccess = {
    type: actionConstants.ENTRIES_REQUEST_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
      entries: Immutable.List(entries)
    }
  }

  beforeEach(function() {
    Dispatcher = require('../../dispatcher');
    EntryStore = require('../entry-store');
    callback = Dispatcher.register.mock.calls[0][0];
  });

  it('should update entries when entries request succeed', function(done) {
    callback(entriesRequestSuccess);
    let all = EntryStore.getState();
    expect(all.size).toBe(3);
  });

});
```

Comment: So, I ended up switching to the stack `mocha`, `chai`, `sinon` and using the solution found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344870/testing-flux-stores-with-mocha-chai-and-sinon) to test stores since I use `mocha` to test my other modules. Thanks @atomrc for the hint that I can use `sinon`  for mocking, I didn't know about it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT]
Ok the first solution I proposed here is actually quite wrong. The bad thing about it is that when really use `dispatch` well it send the action to all the tested stores. So you end up having all your stores called while only testing a single one. That's a side effect you might not want.

So I came up with a far better and simplier solution. The idea : **simply mock the `isDispatching` method of the `dispatcher`** to always return `true`.
This way your stores won't complain when calling the `emitChange` method. For example with `sinon.js`

```
sinon.stub(dispatcher, "isDispatching", function () { return true; });
```

It looks a lot better isn't it ? :)

---------------------**PREVIOUS SOLUTION**------------------------

THIS IS NOT A VIABLE SOLUTION!!

Well looking at this piece of code (https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/src/stores/FluxStore.js#L131) and because `state.merge()` method calls the `__emitChange()` method, I guess we cannot test our stores with a mocked dispatcher.

So I ended up not mocking my dispatcher and simply call the `dispatch` method in my tests.

```
var dispatcher = require("path/to/appDispatcher")
     UserStore = require("path/to/userStore");

var userStore = new UserStore(dispatcher);

it("should load user datas", function () {
    var user = {
       firstname: "Felix",
       lastname: "Anon"
    };


    //actually dispatch the event
    dispatcher.dispatch(actions.RECEIVE_USER, { user: user });
    //test the state of the store
    expect(userStore.get()).to.be(user);
});
```

I guess this is an acceptable solution even if it is not the one suggested in the official doc.